# jQuery interfering with Twitter bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

While creating a website using Twitter Bootstrap's carousel, it seems that some scripts are interfering from it auto-sliding when the website is loaded. But it works fine once you click one of the controls in the carousel. It then slides every 5 seconds, the default time.

I'd rather not post a jsfiddle because of the size, so the [production website](http://pro-intermediair.nl) will have to do (not sure if this is against the rules - otherwise I'll delete it).

Now there are some plugins I'm using (Newsletter and Contact Form 7) which also include scripts from jQuery. I'm not sure how to implement the noconflict from jQuery, or if it will even help.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: I notice in my Chrome console that: Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined. That might be messing things up a bit.

Comment: Are you using jQUery in noConflict mode?

Comment: The modernizr was because I was moving javascript around to see what was interfering - forgot to put it back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by saving a copy of your site to my local drive, I moved the bootstrap .js file to the bottom of the file right above `</body>` and called the carousel manually so it ends up looking like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./PRO-Intermediair   Your Next Step!_files/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel();
</script>
</body></html>
```

**edit**

I posted a copy so you can see  http://tctel.com/pro/

Comment: WOW, that actually worked. Spent hours moving the scripts around to no avail. Thanks a lot for this fix.